# Illustrator, snap to guide

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm attempting to place the end of a line segment at the intersection of a circle and a guide in Adobe Illustrator:

[image: illustration]

I'm expecting the end of the line to snap into place at the intersection, but with no luck. Smart Guides and Snap to Point are turned on.

Here is a short video of the problem: http://cl.ly/K3tr

I'm using this guide/tutorial in order to *"...connect a tangent line to a curved segment in order to create a smooth geometrically correct transition from a curve to a straight line..."* - [Tangent Lines to Curved Segments](http://dribbble.com/shots/468882-Tangent-Lines-to-Curved-Segments)

Is anyone familiar with this method that could shed some light on why it's not snapping?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your snap to distance? Tried increasing it (in the pref)? Is Align to Pixel Grid turned on?

Comment: @Scott I played with that. I settled on 8. The guide I mentioned in the question said the max is 10. Short clip of the problem: http://cl.ly/K3tr

Comment: I think it's just the poor performance of snapping. Heck, even smart guides are often "off" by a few pixels. If you click-drag on the end anchor point you'll have better luck with it snapping to the intersection. However, Smart Guides will never show that intersection. Honestly.... bug in Illustrator. Snapping/Smart Guides have been pretty bad the last few versions.

Comment: @Scott That was it!! Thank you! I was click-dragging from the middle of the line instead of from the end anchor point. I see now that snapping is based on the point you have clicked. Reply as an answer so I can mark the question as answered. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just the poor performance of snapping. Heck, even smart guides are often "off" by a few pixels.

**If you click-drag on the end anchor point you'll have better luck with it snapping to the intersection. Snapping is often dependent upon the position of the cursor.**

However, Smart Guides will never show that intersection. Honestly.... bug in Illustrator. Snapping/Smart Guides have been pretty bad the last few versions.